# Web Scraping a list of links from Tripadvisor

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to create a webscraper that will return a list of links to individual objects from the website [example website](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g187427-Activities-oa60-Spain.html).
The code I wrote takes the list of pages and returns the list of links to each attraction, but in the wrong way (the links are not one after the other):

[image]
Could someone help me to correct this code so that it would take list of links like below?
[image]

I will be grateful for any help.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
}

restaurantLinks = open('pages.csv')
print(restaurantLinks)
urls = [url.strip() for url in restaurantLinks.readlines()]


restlist = []
for link in urls:
    print("Opening link:"+str(link))
    response=requests.get(link, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='cNjlV')
    print(productlist)

    productlinks =[]
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append('https://www.tripadvisor.com'+link['href'])

    print(productlinks)

    restlist.append(productlinks)

print(restlist)

df = pd.DataFrame(restlist)
df.to_csv('links.csv')
```

Comment: *the links are not one after the other* - some details and expected result to clarify would be great and improve your question - May take a minute to focus and read: How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `append()` elements to your list try to `extend()` it:

```
restlist.extend(productlinks)
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
}
urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g187427-Activities-oa60-Spain.html']
restlist = []

for link in urls:
    print("Opening link:"+str(link))
    response=requests.get(link, headers=header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    restlist.extend(['https://www.tripadvisor.com'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('a:has(h3)')])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(restlist)
df.to_csv('links.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks so much better. But how do I get rid of the numbering in the first row and first column (like on the first screen in question)?

Comment: Set index parameter to False -> `df.to_csv('links.csv', index=False)`